# An open source software/ecosystem I can use to quickly create faceted search UIs for CSV files in the range of 20 - 100 GBs?

Tags: data, search-engine, csv

**Problem**

I have some large CSV files between 20 GB to 100 GB. The data can be useful to a lot of non technical people, each of whom will only be interested in a slice of data. I could distribute the whole data dump, but most of them will not be able to make use of it.

Although I can save these datasets on some database and create UIs but it requires a lot of effort, I would rather have the indices and UI develop automatically or use components people have developed to solve sub problems.

Thse are some features I need to have.

**Required Features**

- Faceted search for all columns of csv.
- Should be able to handle filtering on numbers, dates, enums and strings.
- Option to download filtered data as csv.
- Should be space efficient.
- UI is created using web technologies (HTML/CSS/JavaScript)
- Full text search is not necessary, in fact I would prefer solutions which don't have it due to simplicity.

I am also considering solutions which could require a bit of coding. I am familiar with python, golang, typescript and react js. I just don't want to develop everything from scratch, a bit of development is fine though.

Any hint in the right direction is appreciated.